# Why is bidrectional search more efficient in BFS?

Tags: algorithm, search

Imagine a line, with two nodes, A in -10, and B in 10, using uni directional search, we search from (-30, 10) and using bi directional search we search from (-20, 0)and (0, 10) and (10, 20). Either way we are searching 40 steps. Now if we expand this with multi neighbor, it is not hard to see that bidirectional is not different than uni directional search. Am I getting something wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the graph of states is a line, then there is no gain. You gain if the number of nodes grows more than linearly in the distance. Compare the area of a circle of radius r (about A) with the area of two circles of radius r/2 (centered at A and B).

[image]

The latter (in green) is smaller. It is more dramatic in more dimensions. In many graphs, the number of nodes grows roughly exponentially with the radius, and then the improvement is larger.

Answer (score 1):

It's not, as a general rule, it can be faster for certain types of sparse graphs. However, since it is at worst as good as a unidirectional search (ie. it will never be slower), and is not significantly more complicated, it is usually preferred.

Lets say that the shortest path has 6 nodes. In a unidirectional you would need to find all 6, let's say every node was connected to 2 other nodes. You would on average have to search about 64 (2^6 nodes to find the shortest path, right? In contrast in a bi-directional algorithm each search would only have to find 3 (or 4, depending on implementation) nodes, which would only require visiting 8 (2^3) or 16 (2^4)  nodes each, for a total of 16 or 32. depending on whether you can end your search when either is a neighbor (the quicker), or when each search has found the same node (the less quicker).

This difference may not seem much in our small graph, but the larger and denser the graph, the more pronounced the difference gets. for a graph with branching factor 6 each node is connected to 6 other nodes, and a distance of 20 (which still isn't a particularly large graph) the numbers would be 3.6*10^15 and 1.2*10^8 which is a difference of 7 orders of magnitude faster. Now imagine this difference scaled up to a graph the size of Google Maps.